# Terminal commands on same line

Tags: php, macos, terminal

using php index.php to echo a simple php file. It echos it like this ..

```
Root-MacBook-Pro:composer-demo root$ php index.php
Jacquelyn Tromp453 Roberts Turnpike
East Nelda, ND 23489 Root-MacBook-Pro:composer-demo root$
```

even the new command line is on the same line with the echo. Want it to be echoed on a different line like this.

```
Root-MacBook-Pro:composer-demo root$ php index.php
Jacquelyn Tromp
453 Roberts Turnpike
East Nelda, ND 23489
Root-MacBook-Pro:composer-demo root$
```

This is my index.php

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$faker = Faker\Factory::create();

echo $faker->name;
echo $faker->address;
```

I can understand why there is no break between the both echo statements but why is the next terminal line also on the same line .. shouldnt it display on the next line?

Answer (score 1):

> I can understand why there is no break between the both echo statements

OK, but just to make it clear, that is because there is no new line character output after the name.

> why is the next terminal line also on the same line

Because there is no new line character output after the address.

---

A shell doesn't insert a line break just because a program has terminated.